How Do I Correctly Count this Rhythm?
I'm studying a transcription for a guitar solo from a Steely Dan song called Your Gold Teeth II but there is a section that has me confused on how to count the rhythm.
The Guitar solo starts at bar 86 and is in 6/8:


In bar 89 there are 2-16th note triplets followed by a 32nd note run but I am confused on how to count this rhythm correctly.
Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.



Each 16th-note triplet takes the time of one eighth-note.
The four 32nd notes take the time of one eighth-note
The 12-tuplet is three groupings of four 32nd-notes, each grouping taking the time of one eighth note.



Awesome!  Thanks!!!

Am having a heck of a time getting the phrasing right on this

@Tikhon Right? It's one thing to count it, but then there's actually trying to play it!

Wow.  Yeah.. for sure...I think Denny Dias is an amazing player.  I was watching a recent interview and this solo was mentioned as being one of his best and I think the interviewer used the word "transcendent", taking his playing to another level of sophistication.  I have to agree.  It's one of my favorite Steely Dan songs of all time.  Thanks again for your help.
